# How to create or render a List of entity for another entity in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I render (Scaffold) list of Tags for a Location having this model in my application:

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.

I want to save a list of Tags against a location and render it back in View and I'm not able to do that!

```
public class Tag
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        // Navigation
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

    }

    public class Location
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public virtual int LocationId { get; set; }
        public virtual string LocationName { get; set; }

        // Navigation
        public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    }
```

**Right now the view just contains the Location name for input:**

[image]

**View -Create Location**

```
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Location</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LocationName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocationName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tags, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tags, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tags, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

It renders fine but doesn't save any tag in database:
[image]

**Here is the problem**

When I'm trying to render back the tags in edit view, it shows like this:

[image]

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @BenRobinson thanks for your reply, I want to create/save a list of tags related to a particular location. Can you please help?

Comment: more specifically what is it that you are unable to do, what problems are you having trying to do what you require?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a custom view/edit templates for your "Tags" property. Refer to this: http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/10/overriding-displayfor-and-editorfor-to-create-custom-outputs-for-mvc/

Comment: Thanks for your David, but I'm not getting how I do that in my scenario...any guess please?